# What is this View called in android?

Tags: android, view

What is the name of this View in the bottom right corner of this image? Is it possible to create your own implementation with the default Android API?

[image]

Comment: yes you can create it. Use `Relative Layout` and use `images or buttons etc` and give attribute `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`

Answer (score 2):

the name of that view is  **Map toolbar**

you can use **[Map toolbar](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls#map_toolbar)** to control that  view

You can disable it using `UiSettings.setMapToolbarEnabled(false)`

> **[UiSettings.setMapToolbarEnabled(false):](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings#setMapToolbarEnabled(boolean))**
>   Sets the preference for whether the Map Toolbar should be enabled or disabled. If enabled, and the Map Toolbar can be shown in the current context, users will see a bar with various context-dependent actions, including 'open this map in the Google Maps app' and 'find directions to the highlighted marker in the Google Maps app'.

**sample Code**

```
GoogleMap googleMap;

googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I'm not trying to disable it, I'm trying to replicate it.

Comment: yes you can replace it first Map toolbar disabled than craete your own view and put that view at end| right of your map @duper51

Answer (score 0):

Use FrameLayout. Views can be overlapped.

```
FrameLayout

View(map)

LinearLayout

    button1

    button2
```

Comment: this doesnot answer OP question at all

Comment: @Redman actually this is closer than the other answers to the answer to my question.

Comment: @duper seriously mate ?, other person answered exactly what you asked for and this guy said what is the use of framelayout .